# Как определить середину объекта и разделить его на две половины

Tags: c#, unity3d

Помогите пожалуйста!
Предположим, есть кот и есть ёлка. Ёлка должна стоять на месте и вращаться (говоря языком физики - падать), а кот должен прыгать на ней. Когда кот на ней то, оттого на какой он половине ёлки зацепился меняется направление вращения(падения). Например, если кот зацепился за левую половину - то ёлка вращается влево, но (немного противореча законам физики :) ) если потом прыгнуть на правую сторону, то ёлка начнёт поворачиваться направо.
Так вот, как же мне понять, на какой половине объекта ёлки сидит кот, если ёлка ещё и вращается? Если бы ёлка она не вращалась, то `if(координаты кота <(или >) ёлка.transform.position.x)` вполне подошло бы. А так, первый прыжок срабатывает, но вот если ёлка под большим уклоном, то определить на какой половине приземлился кот - невозможно.
Может кто-нибудь знает?

Comment: Говоря по людски - падать это падать, а вращаются либо по часовой, либо против часовой.

Comment: Вспоминайте школьную геометрию. В прямоугольном треугольнике проекция гипотенузы на ось x равна произведению длины гипотенузы умноженную на косинус угла между осью и гипотенузой., на ось y - произведению гипотенузы умноженную на синус угла.

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю такое решение задачи.

1. Создаем иерархию

```
пустой обьект
    |---Елка 
          |---- кот
```

Пустой обьект собой являет пивот по которому елка вращается.

Кот это подобьект елки. Он нужен внутри елки для того что бы мы могли обращатся не к глобальной системе координат, а локальной -- елочной.

2. Таким макаром можно без всяких расчетов ориентироватся расположению кота на центр елки и смотреть только больше или меньше нуля наша координата кота относительно елки.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Обязательно попробую

Comment: Так если я буду цеплять кота как подобъект ёлки, то при вращении пустого объекта кот тоже будет вращаться

Comment: Ну да. А тебе нужно что бы он оставался висеть в воздухе?)

Comment: Прикол в том, что по минимальным законам физики ёлка должна продолжить падение даже после того как кот с неё спрыгнул. Когда кот спрыгивает, то он падает с учётом поворота родительского объекта. Мне это не нужно)
К тому же, я уже нашёл ответ) Использовал Vector3.Dot https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Dot.html
Спасибо за внимание)

Comment: в момент падения можно вынести кота из иерархии елки, обнулить поворот и отпрыгнуть в нужную сторону с анимацией. Фактически переместить кота из локальной системы координат в глобальную. То есть на самом деле проблемы здесь вообще нет.