# возможно ли в unity изменить начало координат объекта? т.е. перенести его, и чтобы новое положение было нулевым по оси X, Z, Y?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-faq

возможно ли в unity изменить начало координат объекта? т.е. перенести его, и чтобы новое положение было нулевым по оси X, Z, Y?

Comment: Скорее нет, чем да. Но вы можете запомнить текущие положение в поле класса, и просто всегда вычитать его :)

Comment: А оно разве не нулевое всегда?

Comment: А зачем? Похоже на проблему XY

Comment: @SergeySkvortsov плохое и неудобное решение

Comment: @МаксимФисман я написал в своем ответе для чего

Comment: @AlemkhanUtepkaliev нет, при импорте обьекта оно всегда по центру. При чем центр может быть там где юнити покажется что там центр - он даже может быть смещен в любую сторону)) Хотя обычно центр правильный.

Comment: ВОПРОС ХОРОШИЙ. ПОЖАЛУСТА, НЕ МИНУСИТЕ И НЕ ЗАКРЫВАЙТЕ ЕГО. Он полезен для ресурса!

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте создать пустой объект, перенесите в него нужные объекты, переместите пустышку в нужную позицию(XYZ) и изменяйте позицию своих объектов через transform.localPosition

Answer (score 2):

Это называется Pivot Point.

Юнити не поддерживает изменение Pivot Point из коробки. И вряд ли когда-нибудь будет.

Решение правильно подсказал Даниил Ганин в своем ответе - необходимо создать пустой обьект и внутрь него положить тот обьект который тебе необходимо. **Пустой обьет в даном случае играет роль самого PivotPoint.**

Для удобности советую сделать наоборот - сначала пустышку внутрь твоего обьекта, сместить куда необходимо, а потом в иерархии поменять местами -- обьект поместить внутрь Pivot-a.

---

С вопросами для чего это используется... Вообще пивот очень широко используется в 3д моделировании, наверное, нету ни одного 3д-редактора который бы не поддерживал изменение пивота.

Это используется, например, что бы дверь открывалась сбоку где находятся петли, а не вращалась по центру оси.

Или, например, если нужно поезд привязать к рельсам - лучше будет если пивот вагона будет находится на уровне колес с (например) левой стороны, а сплайн по которому поезд движется - будет находится на самой рельсе. Это вместо кучи костылей. И тогда мы просто реализуем передвижение по рельсам двигая обьект по сплайну (в даном случае пивот)

Иной пример использования: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1205667/186752

Вобщем, вопрос очень полезен и использование пивота играет очень важную роль в геймдеве.

Comment: а если твой объект спавнится при старте, что тогда делать?

Comment: @Анатолий ты можешь создать готовый префаб сразу с таким вот пивотом как я описал и спавнить сколько угодно